# Spliting data frames in R by comparing values in 2 columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame as below

```
ID1 ID2 INT
aaa qqq 1
aaa ccc 2
aaa nnn 1
aaa yyy 1
bbb nnn 3
bbb aaa 4**
ccc ddd 3
ddd bbb 1***
ppp yyy 2
ppp ccc 1
mmm bbb 1***
mmm ppp 2
nnn ccc 2
```

I want to split the data into new data frames as show below, where any occurrence of the ID in either ID1 or ID2 is grouped as shown below?

```
For aaa     
 ID1     ID2 INT
aaa      qqq  1
aaa      ccc  2
aaa      nnn  1
aaa      yyy  1
aaa      bbb  4**
```

The 4th row in this data frame is the 6th row in the original data where ID2 is 'aaa'

```
For bbb     
ID1 ID2 INT
bbb nnn 3
bbb aaa 4
bbb ddd 3***
bbb mmm 2***
```

How could I do this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the example data:

```
df <- read.table(text="ID1 ID2 INT
aaa qqq 1
aaa ccc 2
aaa nnn 1
aaa yyy 1
bbb nnn 3
bbb aaa 4
ccc ddd 3
ddd bbb 1
ppp yyy 2
ppp ccc 1
mmm bbb 1
mmm ppp 2
nnn ccc 2", header=TRUE)
```

Melt `df` into long format and simultaniously create a new variable that combines the values of `ID1` and `ID2` with the `reshape2` package:

```
require(reshape2)
df2 <- melt(df, id=c("ID1", "ID2","INT"), measure=c("ID1", "ID2"), variable = "ID")
```

Split dataframe in list of dataframes:

```
dfs2 <- split(df2, df2$value)
```

Selecting a specific dataframe of the list with one of these two possibilities:

```
dfs2$aaa
dfs2[[aaa]]
```

Creating seperate dataframes:

```
list2env(split(df2, df2$value), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Save each dataframe in the list to a seperate file:

```
lapply(seq_along(dfs2), function(i) write.csv(dfs2[i], file = paste0(names(dfs2)[i],'.csv')))
```

Comment: The split helps split the data based on column ID1, I have rephrased the question, is there a way to do it where an element can occur in ID1 or ID2 to get the list as mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from the question what exactly you would like to do! Regex or grep might be your friend here

```
grep('a b', c('cc', 'c a b c', '123'))
>2
```

Is there a pattern to search for?

Comment: I didn't format the question clearly, this being my first post. I have a big data frame where this is required!

Comment: Use subset? e.g. new.data.frame = subset(data.frame, ID1 == 'aaa') How big is big

Comment: Big here would be more than 10000 rows! And on using subset subset(data.frame, ID1 == 'aaa') I only get the rows with ID1=="aaa" but not ID2=="aaa". If you see the final result, it has the ID1 and ID2 reversed in case of the data frame for aaa (aaa  bbb 4) being the 4th row where as it is the 6th row in the data (bbb  aaa 4).

Comment: new.data.frame = subset(data.frame, ID1 == 'aaa' | ID2 == 'aaa') and then use an ifelse statement? ifelse(data.frame$ID1=='aaa', data.frame$ID1, data.frame$ID2) and the reverse for the second column?